# How to replace New line and ^M chars with ~~ in Unix

Tags: file, unix, replace, sed, newline

I am not good at unix.

I have a csv file which I is having multiple columns. Out of which, one column is containing new line and `^M` chars. I need to replace all of them between two " (which is a single cell value) by `~~` so that I can treat the cell value as single field. Here is the sample file :

```
"id","notes"
"N001","this is^M
test.

Again test

"
"N002","this is perfect"
"N00345","this is

having ^M
problem"
```

I need this file like :

```
"id","notes"
"N001","this is~~test.~~~~Again test~~~~"
"N002","this is perfect"
"N00345","this is~~~~having ~~problem"
```

So that the whole cell value can be read as a single field value.

I need to add one more case in this requirement where data within a cell contains `"` (double quotes). Here in this case we can identify ending `"` when it is followed by comma. Here are updated case data :

```
"id","notes"
"N001","this is^M
test. "Again test."

Again test

"
"N002","this is perfect"
"N00345","this is

having ^M
problem as it contains "
test"
```

We can keep `"` or remove it. The expected output is :

```
"id","notes"
"N001","this is~~test. "Again test."~~~~Again test~~~~"
"N002","this is perfect"
"N00345","this is ~~~~having ~~problem as it contains "~~test"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `sed`

```
sed -i -e 's/^M//g' -e '/"$/!{:a N; s/\n/~~/; /"$/b; ba}' file
```

**Note :** To enter `^M`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

File content after running command

```
"id","notes"
"N001","this is~~test.~~~~Again test~~~~"
"N002","this is perfect"
"N00345","this is~~~~having ~~problem"
```

---

**Or** using `dos2unix` followed by `sed`

```
dos2unix file
sed -i '/"$/!{:a N; s/\n/~~/; /"$/b; ba}' file
```

---

**Short Description**

Idea here is to remove newline character in each line not ending with `"`

```
sed -i '              # -i specifies in-place relace i.e. modifies file itself
  /"$/!{              # if a line doesn't contain end pattern, " at the end of a line, then do following
    :a                # label 'a' for branching/looping
      N;              # append the next line of input into the pattern space 
      s/\n/~~/;       # replace newline character '\n' with '~~' i.e. suppress new lines
      /"$/b;          # if a line contains end pattern then branch out i.e. break the loop
      ba              # branch to label 'a' i.e. this will create loop around label 'a'
  }                   
' file                # input file name
```

Refer to [**`man sed`**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) for further details

---

**EDIT**

> Sometimes data in the cell itself contains " within it.

Using `sed`

```
sed -i ':a N; s/\n/~~/; $s/"~~"/"\n"/g; ba' file
```

File content after running command for updated  case data

```
"id","notes"
"N001","this is~~test. "Again test."~~~~Again test~~~~"
"N002","this is perfect"
"N00345","this is~~~~having ~~problem as it contains "~~test"
```

---

Using `perl` *one-liner*

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\n/~~/g; s/"~~("|$)/"\n$1/g;' file
```

Comment: Hi, your sed command works perfect I guess. But it prints the output on the console rater than saving it in the same file. do I use -i option for that? Please reply. Many Thanks.

Comment: @user3021141 yes, you need to use `-i` option for in-place replace. Updated my answer.

Comment: jkshah, you are master in unix. Thanks a lot. But still one problem, while I run single sed command, I see that ^M are not yet replaced in the file.

Comment: @user3021141 you're welcome, nothing like that, I'm still learning. It might have happened because you might have literally typed `^M` did you type `Ctrl+V` and `Ctrl+M` ? If that's becoming trouble, I would recommend `dos2unix` option

Comment: No I tried as you specidied to print ^M. No worries, I will try second option. Anyway you are excellent Gujju. Thanks.

Comment: Would you please tell me what you have done here in first sed command?

Comment: @user3021141 sure, give me some time, I will provide brief description.

Comment: Hi Mr Shah, can you please tell me now? Thanks.

Comment: hi, Sorry to say but I have one more problem in this case. Sometimes data in the cell itself contains " within it.

Comment: @user3021141 Sorry for greater delay, I had been away from SO. Now updated answer with short description of sed command. I hope it helps.  Since branching in sed not a trivial task, it will clear after a little bit of practice. I encourage you to google on sed branching.

Comment: @user3021141 Regarding *Sometimes data in the cell itself contains " within it.*, Please check **EDIT** in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is working. Just thinking if I can remove the double quotes within cell values completely. so my records will be like

"id","notes"
"N001","this is~~test. Again test.~~~~Again test~~~~"
"N002","this is perfect"
"N00345","this is~~~~having ~~problem as it contains ~~test"

I am not sure if you can see it properly but I just need to remove all the double quotes within starting and ending double quotes. I tried a lot but failing.

Comment: @user3021141 Try `perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\n/~~/g; s/"~~("|$)/"\n$1/g; s/(?<!^)(?<!,)"(?!,|$)//gm' file`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `sed` command

**To replace '^M' alone**

```
sed -i 's|^M|~~|g' file_name
```

**Edit:**
Thanks for giving comment.

Adding a statement to replace '^M and new line'

**To replace '^M and new line'****

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s|^M\n|~~|g' file_name
```

To get '^M' in console you should press `Cntrl+v+m` together

Comment: still need the ~~ for \n between quote

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr`.

```
$ tr '<Ctrl>+m' '~'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\^M/~~/;t nextline
b
: nextline
N
s/\n/~~/
s/^[^"]*\("[^"]*"\}\{1,\}[^"]*$
t
b nextline
"
```

not just change the **^M** but also the new line between quote.

**^M** is obtain in unix session with a **CTRL+V** followed by a **CTRL+M** on keyboard